# I can't work out how to tree shake chartjs with vue3

Tags: chart.js

I'm trying to tree shale chart.js with vue3 but dont know what i'm doing, I currently import the whole chart.js using: import Chart from 'chart.js/auto'  but how can i import only the needed bits , so as to make ny build smaller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as stated in the [docs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.9.1/getting-started/integration.html#bundlers-webpack-rollup-etc) here you need to import and register all the elements you are using:

```js
import {Chart, DoughnutController, ArcElement} from 'chart.js';

Chart.register(DoughnutController, ArcElement)
```

Instead of importing the `DoughnutController` and `ArcElement` you need to import and register the elements you are using.

Comment: ok, i've swapped to this but not seeing any reduced size in the build size?// import Chart from 'chart.js/auto'

import { Chart, LineController, LineElement, PointElement, ArcElement, BarController, BarElement, RadarController, CategoryScale, LinearScale, RadialLinearScale, Filler, Legend, Tooltip } from 'chart.js'

Chart.register(LineController, LineElement, PointElement, ArcElement, BarController, BarElement, RadarController, CategoryScale, LinearScale, RadialLinearScale, Filler, Legend, Tooltip)

Comment: You are importing a lot so it won't make it a lot smaller also you need to make sure you are using V4 since there were some bugs in v3

Comment: ye, i'm using v4

Comment: Well in that case since you are importing almost everything there is not much of a difference

Comment: i'm importing 3 charts, line, bar and radial.  Thats less than half the charts available

Comment: But under the hood they share a lot of things so you import a lot still and the plugins also add a lot

Comment: seems like there is no point to it then, if you use more than one chart